# Conclusion of result of work of the Linux service?

Tags: linux, debian

Is automatically started as service at start of system a script. For example: myscript.service

Question - how to look through work (conclusion) of my script in real time. By analogy as though I have started the script from the terminal and I see a conclusion of work of a script.

service myscript status removes several lines and doesn't update a conclusion

Comment: I don't understand the question, and it doesn't seem to have anything to do with programming. Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: This may help, too: [debian check status of service](https://www.google.com/search?q=debian+check+status+of+service)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
journalctl -f -u myscript
```

Assuming you have used the systemd capabilities.

Either redirect> logs to the file and the tail -f command